# How to force RABL to output XML as default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, rabl

How do I force XML output with RABL? It renders JSON as default, which works fine. When I access my page with

`curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -X GET (myurl)`

RABL renders XML as expected. However, when I access the same URL with a browser, the response is in JSON.
I tried setting

`ActionView::Template::Handlers::Rabl.default_format = Mime::XML`

as well as

`render "index.rabl", :content_type => 'application/xml'`

In that case, rails returns application/xml as content type but still returns JSON.

How can I render the XML representation of my data without sending `application/xml`as the only accept header?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a default format to your route:

```
get 'your/url/matcher' => 'controller#method', :defaults => { :format => :xml }
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Rails are you on? I am pretty sure if you do this for instance:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.xml # renders rabl as xml
  format.json # render rabl as json
end
```

But that's in Rails 2. I am sure there is an equivalent for 3.

Comment: I'm on Rails 3. Hm, adding this block strangely renders an empty page. I get the XML (even without the block) when I append `.xml` to my URL, but it would be nice to have it working without that.

Comment: Yeah this is unlikely to work on Rails 3. Have you considered just adding a simple before filter that sets the content type to XML for that action?